# Passing in "console.log" into subscribe() for an observable

Tags: typescript, observable, console.log

Usually, when I want to print some results from an observable, I go as follows.

```
const source = interval(3000);
const transform = source.pipe(scan((acc, num) => [...acc, num], []));
transform.subscribe(res => console.log("%c" + res, "color:orange;"));
```

Today, I noticed that I can pass `console.log` into the observable like this.

```
const source = interval(3000);
const transform = source.pipe(scan((acc, num) => [...acc, num], []));
transform.subscribe(console.log);
```

It's neat and I like it. The thing is that I haven't managed to pass in the extra parameters to impose CSS on the stuff being console-out'ed and it got me thinking that perhaps it's something totally different I'm passing in than the good old `console.log()` to begin with. (Naively passing in the parameters into `subscribe()` produced an error.) Googling for explanation resulted only in how to log console without any discussion on how else or why not.

Can I pass extra parametering into `console.log` while using the syntax for `subscribe` in the second sample? If so, how? If not, why?

Here's a [Blitzy](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-qegyfz?file=index.ts) to play with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you didn't fully understand how lambdas work (or never realized it), so let me try to enlight you. ;-)

Whenever a function gets a function as paramter, you can either provide the method to be used or write an anonymous function right in the place by using the fat arrow operator (you could also use the typescript or javascript way to write a function).

Then the outer method gets your method as a paramter and calls it with the parameters. Due to the fact, that your outer method `.subscribe()` expects a method with one argument and no return value, the method `console.log(text: string)` perfectly matches, thous allowing the shorter writing.

Unfortunately, whenever this exact match doesn't meet your requirements, you have to define an inline function that calls the inner method with the desired changed parameters.

So, whenever you have something like `foo((a, b, c) => this.something(a, b, c)) you could rewrite it to` foo(this.something)`. But as soon as you like to change the smallest thing on this like parameter order or adding a constant value to one parameter (like in your case) than you can't use the shorthand writing.

#### Update

Ups, just forgot about the *binding* in JS and TS. So the fat arrow operator has also a second job. It ensures that `this` points to the expected object when you look at the code. So the shorthand writing in JS and TS only really works if the outer method has the same `this` as the inner one (what is never true in Rx), which means even if parameter order exactly matches, you have to take the fat arrow operator and the shorthand only works for some global static methods like `console.log()`.

Comment: It's a freakishly good answer. I don't like it one bit. But it's still freakishly good. Thanks you for enlightening me. One uses lambdas in a certain way so much that one becomes blinded (or rather loses awareness) of the actual machinery under the hood. And then, one ends up asking dumb questions.    :)